# HTML layout is not showing up correct in Mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a  website. It works all fine in all the browser but it does not work fine in Mobile browsers. Google ads are destroying the layout. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way other than

- either you remove your ads or
- use ads with smaller dimensions
- or use [responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about responsive ad units!